# Completely closing an app I developed myself on windows phone 8.1 and Windows 8.1

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1

I'm developing an universal game for both windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1 and
everything is working fine, however I'm just not able to fully close it after hitting either the 'X' on windows or the back button on windows phone, it just keeps running in the background on both OS.

Any way to close the app for good?

**Note:** *I'm using HTML5 and JS*

Comment: Most phones leave apps running in the background, and they have task managers if the user wants to close it for real. Not sure if that's set in stone or if the OS allows overrides

Comment: So on Windows 8.1 you've tried hitting Alt + F4? And on Windows Phone 8.1 you've tried holding the back button, then hitting the "X" that shows up on the app?

Comment: On most apps I've used, when the user finds himself on the main menu or some place where you can't return to any other function on the app, it closes down after hitting the back button. That is without having to hold down the back button and hitting the X to close it. I'd like the app to close after hitting the back button only once, without holding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This the default(Standard) behavior for windows phone 8.1 and windows 8.1 winRT apps now. Apps are not closed when user press back button on the home screen.